# Disable .htaccess rule to a specific directory

Tags: .htaccess, https, apache2

I have a Rule in My base folder .htaccess file. The rule will automatically redirect http:// to https://. But for a specific folder or URL I need to access through http://

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

For example My website will be like https://<>/power/a/1

But I need to access some URL without https://

expected http://localhost/admin/rest_api/api_methods/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

# Turn SSL on for /user/login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/rest_api
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL off everything but /user/login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/rest_api
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement an "exception rule" in form of a condition for the `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webservices/access
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Edit: I just realized that the suggestion shown so far would create an endless rewriting loop. So you have to add _a second_ condition to prevent rewriting, when the request already uses https. I adjusted the suggestion above.

Comment: I have added the Above changes to my .htaccess file. but its not working.

Comment: "its not working" is not helpful here. What does that mean? Nothing happens at all? You get an error? The rewriting targets a wrong url? The universe implodes?

Comment: I made a small edit to the first condition in the code above. Maybe that helps?

Comment: when i add the above changes to my .htaccess. The expected result is not working. when i access the URL http://localhost/webservice/access it should not redirect to https:// But after adding your code it work same as before. it is redirecting to https://

Comment: Hm, the code above is working, no problem there. Where is that .htaccess file located? Is it evaluated _at all_? So are .htaccess style files enabled? It is placed in the correct directory? What happens if you create a clear syntax error in there?

Comment: My .htaccess file is located in root path. that is outside webservice folder. let me know where to place the .htaccess file

Comment: Well, it must be located in the `DocumentRoot` folder as defined in your host configuration. So that folder where all your documents are located. Something like `/srv/www/htdocs` or similar. Not sure, but could it be you did not yet read the documentation of the rewriting module? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I corrected a typing mistake once more, please copy the current version from above again. And I tested a little: the redirection works for me as requested, but there indeed appears to be a problem: all is fine if the request has anything _after_ the path, so anything like `/webservices/access/5`, or even just with the trailing `/`. Without that indeed the request is redirected to https which is wrong. This appears to be the effect of the auto index feature of apache which appear to get applied _before_ out rules here come into effect. Hm...

Comment: The problem I was facing (and probably this is also what you stumble upon): there was no resource /webservices/access on my test system here. First this is not a problem, since still the exception does not get applied, as requested. However because of nothing to serve an error is raised and apache internally redirects to the ErrorDocument. _That_ one indeed does _not_ match the exception, thus it is redirected to https... So basically: the above rules are working as requested. Make sure that /webservices/access actually works and produces some form of reply.

Comment: http://localhost/smartrack/webservice/assets/1 am expecting the Result should be like this. But it is redirect to https://localhost/smartrack/webservice/assets/1 .

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see a difference there.

Comment: see the difference in href link

Comment: Well, the second one is using https, if that is what you mean. But I thought that is the whole point of this exercise: to redirect to https. If you expect that the discussed _exception_ should match here, then sorry, it won't: there never was a mentioning of that folder `smartrack` before. If the exception should be for urls along the path `/smartrack/webservice/assets` that is something different to what you asked above. This is possible, but the RewriteRules cannot _guess_ that.

Comment: Sorry. The Sample URL is from my Development Sever. The Actual Production server is having a URL http://localhost/webservice/assets/1

Comment: As said above: for me the rules work as expected, requests to `/webservice/assets/` are _not_ redirected from http to https. There must be some different situation on your production system. I suggest you start enabling rewrite logging (see the excellent documentation of the apache module: [link]http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html). It tells you in detail what is going on inside the rewriting engine.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webservices/access
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It will redirect everything but the `/webservices/access` folder (or any other links in that folder like `/webservices/access/login.php`) to `https`

Comment: Above changes is not working. It is redirecting to https when i access the URL http://localhost/webservice/access