# Disable .htaccess RewriteEngine for specific directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm running an website using apache2.

My websites software is using the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)$ gallery/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^board/(.*)$ board/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

I don't want the redirects to be applied to the URL path **/acp**.

How can I make an exception so that the RewriteRules are enabled for everything excepted **/acp**?

I tried to alter the last Rewrite Block [following this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292064/disable-htaccess-rule-to-a-specific-directory), without success.

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/acp
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: "without success" - Presumably the request is still rewritten? Have you made sure you are not seeing a cached response? Does `/acp` exist as a physical directory?

Comment: ``/acp`` is a physical directory on the server. I'm testing by opening an inkognito tab each time I made changes. There's no cache I guess?

Comment: What is the actual request / response you are seeing? If `/acp` is a physical directory then a request for `/acp` will result in a 301 redirect to `/acp/` (to append the trailing slash) and your original rule would already exclude such requests?

Comment: Chrome says ``ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS``. The directory URL I'm trying to open is ``/acp/index.php?<page>/``. I'm not sure if that's the info you wanted.

Comment: What URL are you requesting? (Or is _that_ the URL you are requesting?) Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? What is the nature of the redirect-loop (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)? From/To what URLs (check the browser network traffic)? There are no "redirects" in the code you posted, so a redirect-loop would not result from this code alone?

Comment: The full URL is https://cor-forum.de/acp/index.php?login/. Looks like it's trying to redirect to the same URL. There are other ``.htaccess`` files in other project directories, unrelated to the forum, is that a problem? They're in some sub-sub-sub-directory, like domain.xyz/project/xyz/xyz, containg stuff like ``php_value display_errors 0``

Comment: "There are other .htaccess files in other project directories" - not a problem. This doesn't look like it has anything to do with the `.htaccess` file you've posted. Try (temporarily) removing the root `.htaccess` file entirely - does it make any difference?